# Deleted pubspec.lock regenerates with newer package versions?

Tags: flutter, pubspec

To repair our `pubspec.lock` file during development, I occasionally delete it and run `flutter pub get` to regenerate it.

What I'm seeing now is, I run `flutter pub get` and no changes are made to the `pubspec.lock` file. But, when I delete `pubspec.lock` and run `flutter pub get`, git shows that several updates to our packages in the regenerated `pubspec.lock` file compared to the one that was deleted.

We're all on flutter 2.8. I've tested this with 2.8.0 and 2.8.1 and there are slight differences between the two, but they both update a dozen or more packages. Most updates are patches but a few are minor updates.

Could be something fundamental I'm not understanding about `pubspec.lock` files? If we're all on the same version of flutter, shouldn't deleting/rebuilding `pubspec.lock` produce an identical file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run pub get, the Pub package manager looks at `pubspec.yaml` and generates the `pubspec.lock` file. This lock file records the exact versions of the packages and their `transitive dependencies` that were resolved during that particular run.

If a package `p` in your `pubspec.yaml` has a dependency on another package `p1` with a caret (`^`) version constraint, like `^1.2.3`, it means that the resolved version of p1 can be any version that is backwards-compatible with the specified version range `(e.g., >=1.2.3 <2.0.0)`.

The `pubspec.lock` file "locks" these resolved versions, including transitive dependencies. This means that no matter how many times you run `flutter pub get`, you will get the exact dependencies of the packages and their transitive dependencies

If you delete the `pubspec.lock` file and run `pub get` again, and if a transitive dependency like p1 has been updated(**not p**, assume p is the same in your `yaml` file) with breaking changes, the new version of p1 will be installed(as it's a transitive dependency).

This would lead to an update in your lock file.

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

A coworker clued me in. Deleting and regenerating the `pubspec.lock` file performs a `pub upgrade`, which is why the packages are newer. Doing a `pub get` does not run `pub upgrade`.

Comment: It didn't work for me. pub get is also getting the newer versions instead of versions from pubspec.yaml file